# Prevent KafkaStreams punctuator from shutting down on CAUGHT exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

Using kafkastreams with Spring Boot, I have an exception that is caught in the punctuator like so:

```
        try {
            return record.toBuilder().apiResponse(userFeed.addActivity(activity).join()).success(Boolean.TRUE).build();
        } catch (StreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return record.toBuilder().success(Boolean.FALSE).build();
        }
```

However, this exception is causing the streams app to shutdown:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [notification-service-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Exception caught while punctuating processor 'KSTREAM-PROCESSOR-0000000001'
```

```
2023-01-20T15:39:33.269Z ERROR 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams : stream-client [notification-service] Encountered the following exception during processing and the registered exception handler opted to SHUTDOWN_CLIENT. The streams client is going to shut down now.
```

How do I change the registered exception handler to not shut down the client? All the docs talk about uncaught exception handlers, but I am catching this exception. I don't even know what the registered handler is.

Comment: It turns out that the exception is not in fact caught correctly because of thread weirdness, so setting the uncaught exception handler fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the exception is not in fact caught correctly because of thread weirdness, so setting the uncaught exception handler fixed this.